# Netbeans 7.4 double quote marks autocomple on new line

Tags: php, netbeans, double-quotes, netbeans-7.4

In Netbeans 7.4 when you hit Return within a set of double quotes it auto-completes using concatenation syntax. i.e.

[image: Netbeans double quote new line autocomplete]

How can I switch this off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well, and boy is it annoying.

The following answer applies to both NetBeans 7 and 8:

- Within NetBeans: Under the top menu (in NetBeans,) click Tools -> Options
- In the pop-up window, go to: Editor -> Code Completion (tab)
- Uncheck `Use String Auto-Concatenation after Types Break`, located at the very bottom

Answer (score 3):

Tools -> Options -> Editor -> Code Completions -> Language: PHP -> Quotes Completion: -> Use Smart Quotes (" and ') Completion.

Comment: Almost "Use String Auto-Concatenation after Typed Break" is what i'm after.

Comment: So.. you did find it thanks to my instructions although they were incorrect at the very end? ;p

Comment: yes but the option is called "Use String Auto-Concatenation after Typed Break"